# Команда loginctl user-status

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, login

*Запустите команду loginctl user-status.
Что выполняет, для чего предназначена эта утилита?*

Как я поняла, она выводит инфу об определенном пользователе? А что означают вот эти строки в большом количестве? Объясните, пожалуйста! Я новичок, плохо понимаю это все. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Список процессов.

Comment: спасибо большое!)

Comment: А циферки - `PID`: https://losst.ru/kak-uznat-pid-protsessa-v-linux

Comment: На будущее. Тексто лучше постить в виде текста, а если нужно всё-таки сделать скрин, то лучше сохранять в `png`.